# Print the complete function where an error happens

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I would like to get the code to be printed of a function when there is an error.
For example I have overwritten the window.onerror function and when there is an error I want to print the complete function.
Of course I get the line number but that does not work for minified js.
I could implement the use of source maps but isn't there a more easy way to get the complete function in which the error happened?
For example:

```
function example(){
     //runs code which works but then an error happens
}
```

Now I want to print not only the one line where the error happened I want to print the whole function.

Comment: Chrome (and IE10) now give you the column number as the fourth argument in the window.onerror callback. So you can detect where is the error in your minfied js.

Comment: That is right but this does only give me the line in which the error happened but I do not know where the function began since I want to get the whole function not just the line with the error.

Comment: Yes, but in modern browsers, you can know the line and the column, so you can know the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror   (column is the fourth arg)

Comment: How can print the complete function when I know the row and the column that is a bit unclear to me at the moment.